# How to extract specific points in Matplotlib graph? (python)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

From an image, I have computed a mean value over each column and created a graph. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8y3P.png) is the output (without letters and marked points).

[image: diagram]

Most graphs have a behavior like graphs marked with blue, green and red color. From those graphs, **I would like to extract point C**. But sometimes A is extracted instead of C. Therefore I would like to find an unambiguous solution.

Idea:

- The interval from A to B is always shorter than C to D.

Problem:

- I don't know how to extract point A, B, C.
- Not all graphs are the same (example: light blue line). How to distinguish between them?

**Edit #1**

[image]

Comment: Please insert your diagram in the question body.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post it in a body. It is attached as a link in a word THIS.
Sorry I am a new member.

Answer (score 0):

The light blue curve being completely different, I would start by detecting it. Fir that I would use three time points (50, 700 and 1400). You see that the values |V50-V700|, |V700-V1400| are completely different for the two types of curves (Blue green red versus light blue).

Then you can detect the A, B and C points. They are characterized by the important and sudden variations (so gradient). I would start by using a median filter in order to denoise a little bit your signals, and then I would compute the signal gradient. A, B and C are going to be the three points with the biggest gradients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see in "Edit 1" I computed gradient, but I don't know how to extract it. Can you provide a code?